# How to reduce one of the duplicate object from array of objects by id

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, reduce

I have an array of objects:

```js
const obj = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'A'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'A'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'A'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'A'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'A'
}]

// this method returned me one object with id=1
const filter = obj.reduce((val, index) => {
  return index === val.findIndex(v => obj.id === v.id && obj.name === o.name)
})
```

When I push the button I want to remove one of the duplicate object. For example I have 3 object within an array with ID=1. I want to remove only one object with ID=1 and not two. So the result must be like this:

```js
const obj = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'A'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'A'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'A'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'A'
}]
```

Comment: your text looks like code and your code looks like text .... please edit the question and make it readable

Comment: Please take the time to proof-read your questions before submitting them. This was, frankly, an unreadable mess before I edited it.

Comment: [MDN on Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce): _"The final result of running the reducer across all elements of the array is a single value."_ - so that is probably not very suitable for what you want here to begin with.

Comment: so if id=2 also had 3 or more  entries, you also wanted that reduced to max 2 entries?

Comment: it's like you try to use your data as queue or stack. i would suggest to restructure your data

Comment: is your list sorted? Because that'll make quite a difference (if it is, you can just track the current id and a boolean "seen" that you set to true once you see a new id. If seens' already true, delete it (and remember that if you're doing this in a loop, iterate last-to-first)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by finding the index of the first object with `id=1` and then using [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove it:

```js
const obj = [ { id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, name: 'A' } ];

const targetId = 1;
const indexToRemove = obj.findIndex(item => item.id === targetId);

if (indexToRemove !== -1) {
  obj.splice(indexToRemove, /*deleteCount=*/1);
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: It is likely there might be more than one set and not only the one with id=1 is to be deduplicated to have max two duplicates

Comment: #WeTakeThose #ThrivingInAmbiguity #PEP20Line20=FakeNews (In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that will take any number of objects and leave a maximum of two duplicates

```js
const filteredObj = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc.count[curr.id] ??= 0; // conditional assignment
  acc.count[curr.id]++;
  // If the count is less than or equal to 2, add the object to the result array
  if (acc.count[curr.id] <= 2) {
    acc.result.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, {
  count: {},
  result: []
}).result;

console.log(filteredObj);
```

```html
<script>
const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: 'A' },
  { id: 1, name: 'A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'B' },
  { id: 2, name: 'B' },
  { id: 3, name: 'C' },
  { id: 1, name: 'A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'B' }
];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Map to count the number of occurrences of an `id`. Use `Array.filter()` to remove all items which `id` is counted more than twice:

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"name":"A"},{"id":1,"name":"A"},{"id":1,"name":"A"},{"id":2,"name":"A"},{"id":2,"name":"A"}]

const ids = new Map()

const result = arr.filter(o => {
  ids.set(o.id, (ids.get(o.id) ?? 0) + 1)
  
  return ids.get(o.id) <= 2
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved through a `TrueSet` representing each item by its `id`.

```
import { TrueSet } from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/TrueSet.js";
import { ORDER } from "@ut8pia/classifier/global.js";
import assert from "assert";

const 
    data = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'A'
    }, {
        id: 1,
        name: 'A'
    }, {
        id: 1,
        name: 'A'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'A'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'A'
    }],

    expected = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'A'
    }, {
        id: 1,
        name: 'A'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'A'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'A'
    }]
```

All you need to do is add your data to the `TrueSet`.

```
const
    repr = item => item.id,
        
    set = TrueSet.of(repr, ORDER.ASCENDING)
        .letAll(data);
```

Every item is stored within an internal tree structure - a `Classifier`, in form of a path of nodes whose keys are `[item.id, item]`. This tree structure is accessible via the `set.classifier` property of the `TrueSet`. The `Classifier` method `views(depth)` navigates through all the subtrees at the specified `depth`. Each returned `view` is a `queue` of items offering a method `select(max)` to select in place only the first `max` items.

```
set.classifier.views(1)
   .each(view => view.select(2));
```

That's all! Now the `TrueSet` can contain at max `2` items per each subtree, hence, per each `item.id`.

You can check the validity of the proposed solution by:

```
assert.deepEqual(set.toArray(), expected)
```

It's worth noting that the `TrueSet` itself is a collection of simple items. The method `set.toArray()` retrieves the initial items, irrespective of their representation within the internal tree structure.